# How to initialize an array pointer object

Tags: c++, object, pointers, constructor

I have a little problem to initialize (constructor) an array pointer of object. See the class below. Class test has 2 variable member, a pointer (value) that will be an array, and his size (size); and a constructor with parameters, and a destructor. In main function, I will create an array pointer of objects, and I have problem with it. If I create a single object like:

- `test obj(4);` it will create a object, and his instance, value array is big 4.

Then if i want to create an array of objects:

```
test *obj;
obj = new test[2]{4,7};
```

I will create 2 object: `obj[0]` that is big 4, and `obj[1]` that is big 7.

So if I want to create more object:

```
test *obj;
obj=new test[100]{/*here I must write 100 numbers*/}
```

and this is the problem.
Because I cant write something like this:

```
test *obj;
obj=new int[100]{4}
```

I want that each value[] (instance of test class) is big 4, and I wont write 100 times "4".
I thought the analogy of declaring array:
If I write `int array[5]={0,0,0,0,0}`, I must write 4 times "0", or I can write also:
`int array[5]={0}` and each value is set to 0. (it's also true that if write `int array[5]={5}`, first index will be 5 and others 0).

Should I use a default constructor? What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
private:
int* value;
int size;

public:
test(int size)
{
    this->size = size;
    value = new int[size];
}

~test()
{
    delete[]value;
}
};
```

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector`?

Comment: Yes it's another possible way. But i would know how to do (just for knowledge).

Comment: `test` doesn't follow rule of 5/3/0. leading to issue with copy/move. using `std::vector` for `value` would solve that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your pointer to initialize each element

```
test *obj = new test[100];
for(size_t i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
{
    obj[i] = test(/*parameters*/);
    /* Remember to provide a move assignment operator
which invalidates the pointer member, otherwise when the
temporary variable is destroyed the new object pointer
member will point to data no more available*/
}

// ...
delete [] obj;
```

However it would be better to use `std::vector`

```
std::vector<test> obj(100, test(/*parameters*/));
```

Using `std::vector` your `test` object is initialized 100 times passing its arguments, using a pointer the allocation (`new test[100]`) will default construct every element, then you are going to assign each element the new value, that's why `std::vector` is a better solution to your problem

Comment: Sorry, i accidentally wrote ```new int[100]```, I've edited the answer

Comment: `prog.cpp:25:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘test::test()’`, and if you add a default constructor, it will crash at runtime.

Comment: For the pointer alternative a default constructor is nedded. About the crash, can you post the error you are receinving?

Comment: It's a double-free.

Comment: Yes, you need a default constructor.  test::test(){ }

Comment: @melpomene: double free is because `test` doesn't follow rule of 5/3/0, and we do copy.

Comment: ```obj[i] = test(/*parameters*/);``` will create a temporary rvalue which will be destroyed after the assignment. If you don't provide a move assignment operator a default one is generated. Note that the default one will not invalidate your pointer member so when the temporary variable is destroyed also the data inside your pointer will be destroyed. ```delete[] obj``` will then destroy that data another time which causes an error. To solve, you have to implement a move constructor or a move assignemnt operator which invalidate the pointer member

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not initialize the elements, it assigns to them.  So it only works if the `test` type is assignable.

Comment: To initialize the pointer ```test``` must be copy constructible. If a type is copy constructible it should be also copy assignable

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate the memory on the stack and get rid of dynamic allocation and memory management.

```
test array[100];
std::fill(std::begin(array), std::end(array), test(100));
```

Note that you would need a default constructor here.